# Repeatedly asked to install firmware update 1.8

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update, firmware

In the last few days I have seen the same update keep appearing in my App Store updates list. The details are:

Software Update: MacBook Air SMC Firmware Update 1.8

"This update address a rare issue on some Apple notebooks where a battery..."

I'm on a Mid-2011 Macbook Air running OS X 10.9.

I have installed the update and the machine reboots as expected, but then a day later the App Store prompts me to install the same update again.

Is there a way to reset or somehow suppress this so I don't keep getting asked?

Comment: I just had to install it twice and it went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on update - Hide update.